# ArcScan equivalent in QGIS

Tags: qgis, vectorization

Is there any thing in QGIS which can perform operations like ArcScan? I put WMS polygon layer as a base map. I save it as PNG and when I add it as a raster layer, I can vectorize it with ArcScan. I want to know if there is anything in QGIS which will function like this.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: Try Raster conversion - Polygonize

Comment: It sounds like what you're really trying to do is just "copy" the data from a WMS service. You should do your due diligence to make sure that isn't a violation of the ToS, as many organizations that don't offer the vector data directly don't intend it to be given out for external use.